# Express server setup with http and https and CORS issue

Tags: express, cors

I have such configuration in express server.js :

```
  app.use(function (request, response, next) {
   response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
   response.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, X-Api-Key'
  );

  next();
})

app.options('*', function (request, response) {
  response.send(200);
});

app.listen(httpPort, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port: ' + httpPort);
});

httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(httpsPort, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port: ' + httpsPort);
});
```

Also I have to enpoints : 
https://local:8000 and http://local:8001

At moment I'm trying to do call from http://local:8001 to https://local:8001/api but getting CORS issue :

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://local:8000/api/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

On Chrome I'm getting :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://local:8000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local:8001' is therefore not allowed access.

How to sort problem with CORS on express server

Answer (score 0):

This sorted my issue:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://local:8001');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, X-Api-Key'
  );
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```