# Node origin even though headers are set

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two URLs on the same server, `mydomain.com` and  `api.mydomain.com`

Now in my API I have added the following to deal with access-origin:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token, Cache-Control, Pragma"
    );
    next();
});
```

However when ever I attempt to make a request to this API I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mydomain.dk/login. Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'https://www.mydomain.dk' is therefore not allowed
> access.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is important, you have to do it before your routes :

[Example Code :](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

I suggest using the [**cors**](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) express module.

---

EDIT :

> [Enable Cors Nodejs Apache](http://www.fvi.edu/Blog/enable-cors-node-js-apache/)
>
> Enabling CORS on apache is a two-step process. First you must create a
>   file with the name .htaccess and add it to the directory where your
>   cross-domain-friendly files are. We recommend you create a new
>   directory for this. The file must contain the following code, (lines 2
>   and 3 may be optional):
>
> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" Header set
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
>   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE,
>   OPTIONS"
>
> The second step in the process is to enable .htaccess files. Test out
>   the CORS requests and see if they are already working (some
>   installations of Apache come with .htaccess files already enabled). In
>   order to test if it’s working, reload apache (using the command below)
>   and then fire your ajax request at your server.
>
> sudo service apache2 restart
>
> If that worked, you’re done. If not, then you need to add the
>   following code inside the VirtualHosts section of your
>   000-default.conf in your /etc/apache2/sites-available folder:
>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>   AllowOverride All Order allow,deny allow from all
>
> Make sure you replace the /var/www/ with the actual path to your
>   document root. Congrats! You’re done!

Comment: is the app behind a reverse proxy like nginx?

Comment: then you also need to config cors for apache :P

Comment: my api works on http however it doesnt work on https do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452425/express-server-setup-with-http-and-https-and-cors-issue