# CORS issues hosting PERN on Railway

Tags: express, http-status-code-503, railway

I have set up hosting of my PERN application on Railway hosting service. I am running into CORS errors, but I am using the Express CORS plugin in my back end and have added the urls that the requests come from.

The specific error message is:

> Access to fetch at 'https://margerin-server.up.railway.app/register' from origin
> 'https://www.marger.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
> doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
> the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to
> 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The request URL is `https://margerin-server.up.railway.app/register`, the request method is OPTIONS, status code is 503. The Origin in Request Headers is https://www.marger.in

So, in my `index.js`, I added:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "https://www.marger.in",
      "https://curvy-push-production.up.railway.app",
      "https://margerin-server.up.railway.app",
      "https://margerin-server.up.railway.app/register",
    ],
  })
);
```

I tried adding both the Railway domain and my own custom domain which it's set up to use.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Sounds like an issue between the edge node and your service. See [503 Service Unavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503). This is **not** a CORS issue

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464264/4797603

Comment: @Phil you are correct, this was an issue with Railway expecting my server to be hosted on a specific port when uploaded to their hosting service.